# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn Python (currently requests and beautifulsoup4) and I found a tutorial [online](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/1872970)

The issue is I keep getting the below error and cannot figure it out at all...

Any help would be appreciated!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\BillyBob\Desktop\Web Scrap.py", line 14, in 
title = a.string.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Here is my code in case I made a mistake;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("http://www.oreilly.com/")

c = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
samples = soup.find_all("a")
samples[0]

data = {}
for a in samples:
    title = a.string.strip()
    data[title] = a.attrs['href']
```

Comment: The `string` attribute of `a` is `None`. You need to look over the documentation for BeautifulSoup and see what `.find_all()` returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first member of `samples` does not have a string attribute, and as a result, `a.string` doesn't return anything, so you're calling the `strip()` method on something that doesn't exist.

However, then you have another problem; it is not necessarily true that `a` has the `href` attribute. Instead, you should check explicitly for both, or else you will get errors (which is the problem with Yevhen's answer, which is otherwise correct).

One potential fix to your problem is to write:

```
for a in samples:
    if not a.string is None:
        title = a.string.strip()
        if 'href' in a.attrs.keys():
            data[title] = a.attrs['href']
```

This way, you check explicitly for each parameter before calling the associated method.

Comment: Good catch. Though I think the main problem is that OP is searching titles within all the links (`.find_all("a")`).

Comment: I would agree with that. I think that using a more selective search would help OP more, as my code papers over the problem.

Answer (score 5):

From [BS4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

I believe you can use `.text` to get what you want:

```
title = a.text.strip()
```

Comment: it sometimes throws `'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @fartwhif, this can never happen with OP's code. If you have that issue, you can ask a question on StackOverflow with your code.

Comment: fair enough, I'm very much a python noob so I don't doubt you hahahah

Comment: @fartwhif - I got the same.